# Wireless configuration solutions?

Tags: wifi

I'm planning to draft a plan for 802.11g wireless network coverage of a distribution center floor. This distribution center is rolling out a new barcode label system. The barcode readers are portable 802.11g wireless network devices. There will also be several dozen Windows XP Professional portable computers that will have 802.11g wireless client adapters accessing this network. The distribution center is approximately 250 feet by 200 feet in size with a 30 foot ceiling. What would be the best solution to accomplish this task? I'm also going to be using Linksys products to implement this project. What are the necessary steps that I must take to configure both the wireless router and the wireless network cards on the PCs in the system? Any ideas or pointers? Any and all help is greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have access to CAD drawings of the facility take a look at Motorola's wireless planning software, I think there is a demo version you could use to bang out one config. You're probably need 6-8 access points with a controller for decent seamless coverage. The shelves seriously nerf the signal.

That's, what I would do at least.